# how to draw a bicolor tcolorbox without frame?

Tags: tcolorbox

Sometimes I want to draw `tcolorboxes` without frames and although I use `boxrule=0pt` some border frame is still visible. I would like to know why.

As an example, take a look at next code which draws a `bicolor` box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{bicolor, colback=blue!15, 
         colbacklower=white, boxrule=0pt}
This is an example of a \emph{bicolor} \texttt{tcolorbox}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the frame around the box is clearly visible. I've tested with
different viewers and all of them show the border.

My opinion is that this border shows a little difference between `frame` dimensions and inner upper and lower parts, but I'm not sure because `boxsep=0pt` doesn't affect it. But `colframe=white` *hiddes* it because the paper is also white. This could be a solution except if background is colorful (like in `beamer`). And I would like to understand what happens.

If I use an `empty` skin nothing except the text is shown, but I don't now how
to reproduce a `bicolor` skin from an `empty` one.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer gave the answer I also would have given. In your case, the frame is drawn as a filled rectangle with near-black color. Then, the same space is filled with the upper and lower part of the bicolor interior. Theoretically, you should see nothing of the frame anymore. But many previewers show a ghost line with 0pt width. `frame hidden` switches the frame drawing completely off.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Thank's for confirming it and for `tcolorbox`, of course!

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Interesting. What if I want a top rule but not the other three? I would set `toprule=2pt` and all others to `0pt`. Then I'd probably get 3 ghost rules that I don't want, and I can't use `frame hidden` in this case.

Comment: @Cyker See the documentation for `borderline north` for a top rule. Alternatively, an `underlay` allows adding additional TikZ code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `frame hidden`

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{bicolor, colback=blue!15,
         colbacklower=white, boxrule=0pt,frame hidden}
This is an example of a \emph{bicolor} \texttt{tcolorbox}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but do you know why the frame is seen even with `boxrule=0pt`?

Comment: Imho pixel rounding. You get a border also with `\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray] (0,0)rectangle (1,1);
\fill[white] (0,0)rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's exactly the reason. `tcolorbox` draws the frame first, then the interior is drawn above.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but you can add `\tcbset{colframe=white}` to your preamble (or locally).

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most,listings]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{colframe=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{bicolor, colback=blue!15,colbacklower=white, boxrule=0pt}
This is an example of a \emph{bicolor} \texttt{tcolorbox}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I already commented, this solution only works if background is also white.

Comment: @Ignasi Oh I had missed that line. Wouldn't setting it using the colour of the background work? Unless the background has multiple colours (which would be quite ugly).

Answer (score 2):

The `frame hidden` option accomplishes what you are asking. Take a look at the documentation of this option (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaQla.png))

See minimal working example below (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfBfZ.png))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins, listings]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum, showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{tcblisting}{
bicolor,
colback = blue!10!white,
colbacklower = blue!5!white,
boxrule = 0pt,
frame hidden,
}
This is an example of a \emph{bicolor} \texttt{tcolorbox}
\end{tcblisting}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Note that i still needed to set the `boxrule` option to `0pt`. Otherwise, the `tcolorbox` environment won't occupy the whole width (see proof [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjMJT.png).)