# how to get corners of the box in latex?

Tags: box

I have created a table in which I have to put this box, any idea how to get this box exactly shown in the image.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an MWE?

Comment: amssymb has $\ulcorner, \urcorner, \llcorner$ and $\lrcorner$.  You could also use a graphics package.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy with a `tcolorbox`.

Next time you ask, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
  enhanced,
  opacityback=0, 
  frame hidden,% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247509/101651
  % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431760/101651:
  overlay unbroken and first ={%
    \draw[thick] ([xshift=10pt]frame.north west) -| ([yshift=-10pt]frame.north west);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift=10pt]frame.south west) -| ([yshift=10pt]frame.south west);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.north east) -| ([yshift=-10pt]frame.north east);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south east) -| ([yshift=10pt]frame.south east);
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
   Something:

   \dotfill

   \dotfill

   \dotfill

   \dotfill
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}
   Something else:

   \dotfill
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @John Kormylo ,   $\ulcorner$ have solved the problem. However, pacakge tcolorbox is fantastic, provides more flexibility.

Comment: @Praveen25488 To reply to John, you have to comment under your question. Once you know `tcolorbox`, you'll never leave it!