# Text and equation environment to have different fonts

Tags: fonts

I have read this [paper](http://www.math.ac.cn/kyry/hcc/hccteach/201512/P020160615514232188602.pdf),
and from what I saw, the font of the text looks exactly like (in fact, I think it is the same as) the `mathpazo` font. 
The font of all the equation environments, however, looks exactly like the Helvetica font. 
I am currently using mathpazo, but I hate how most of the notation especially the summation sign looks. I want the fonts of the text and the equation environment of my paper to look exactly like what is in the above paper. How do I make that possible? My `\documentclass` is `article`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. To find out which fonts are contained in a pdf file, just click on File -> Properties and click on the "Fonts" tab. A separate comment: Instead of asking people to download and leaf through a 200+-page pdf file, please consider editing your posting to show a (reasonably high resolution) screenshot of the a representative page that features both text and math material.

Comment: Could you say which equations use Helvetica?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is URW Palladio the text IMHO.

Comment: It is used only for the auyhor's name, and the real font is ArialMT. The maths font seems to be Computer Modern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text font seems to be similar to Palatino, which can be used with the `newpx` package, and the math font seems to be the standard computer modern. To change only the text font, you can load the package `newpxtext`. For example, using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Let \(\omega \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}\) be a constant. If \(f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\), then its \emph{Fourier transform} is \(\mathscr{F}f\) or \(\hat{f} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}\) defined by
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{F}f(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\omega i x \cdot \xi} f(x) dx
\end{equation}
for all \(\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n\).
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

we get the definition
[image]

and this is the corresponding text from the original document:
[image]

Comment: Finally, I have been able to lay my hands on what I have been looking for all this while. It is indeed what Vincent suggested. Thank you, @Vincent.

Comment: I give to Caesar what is Caesar's. Very good.

Comment: Just a quick one. @Vincent, do you have an idea of how they colored those theorem environments and those of definitions?

Comment: @Ujan Maybe with the [``tcolorbox``](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package. It's certainly a good way to achieve this.

Comment: I have tried that, but around the text is an outline, which I do not need. Do you have an idea about how to eliminate it?

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: @Vincent, how do I get the colored backgrounds for the theorem and equation environments as done in the original article, please?

Comment: @Ujan It can be done with [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247509/201628) to remove the border around a `tcolorbox`. If you're having trouble achieving this, you could ask another question and someone will be able to answer with code, that might help.

Comment: Thank you. It worked

Comment: @Vincent, one more question, please: Looking at the paper http://www.math.ac.cn/kyry/hcc/hccteach/201512/P020160615514232188602.pdf, what paper size could that be? I know it's smaller than an A4 paper but larger than an A5 paper size. Please help. By the way, it is the same paper I previous asked a question about.

Comment: I have figured it out. I think it's either a B5 or an executive paper

Answer (score 1):

The different font families were designed to have an harmonious, pleasing look when used together. Don't mix willy-nilly. Take a look at Peter Wilson's "A few notes on book design" (available as memdesign on CTAN). Typesetting is an art and a profession with it's rules, product of literally centuries of experience. Yes, you *can* break the rules, they aren't set in stone, our present tools allow any random user freedoms that couldn't be dreamed of by professionals with the best that was available a few decades back. But better understand their rationale before doing so.

Comment: Thank you, @vonbrand. The question has already been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

A good sans-serif companion for Palatino is Optima (also available as the clone URW Classico).  A math font that matches Palatino well is Euler.  All three fonts are by the same designer.

Some ways you can get them:

- If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can load `unicode-math`, set the Roman font to Palatino (TeX Gyre Pagella), the sans-serif font to Optima (URW Classico), Asana Math as the main math font, and the math letters from Neo Euler.
- In PDFLaTeX, you can load the packages `tgpagella`, `classico` and `eulerpx` to set up your font families. You must run the `getnonfreefonts` script from CTAN to get `classico`.
- If you want the sans-serif math font, you can use `mathastext`, `sansmath` or (in XeLaTeX) `mathspec` with `newpxmath`.